# Get values from a column based on other column

Tags: python

I want to extract the values of a data frame with a condition from another column of the same df.

```
    A    B
0   2    10
1   3    60
2   7    50
3   1    100
```

I want to grab only `A` values > 2 from but from `B`, and fill in the ones that I grabbed from `B` with a fixed value = 5

Like this:

```
    A    B
0   2    5
1   3    60
2   7    50
3   1    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.where`:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].where(df["A"].gt(2), 5)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  2   5
1  3  60
2  7  50
3  1   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
df['B'] = np.where(df['A']>2,df['B'],5)
df
   A   B
0  2   5
1  3  60
2  7  50
3  1   5
```